# Checking for most recent value on multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

I am trying to use the following dataframe to recreate a dataset with only one line per country where I fetch the most recent value available for each column. If 2019 has available data, I keep it, if not I move on to 2018 and so on. Being new to Python and coding in general, I have tried to find a starting point for this but I am struggling as no solution I found up to now seems to work.

```html
                 Population totale      PIB en $  Superficie
country     year
Aruba       2019           106314.0           NaN         NaN
            2018           105845.0           NaN       180.0
            2017           105366.0  2.805918e+09       180.0
            2016           104872.0  2.750900e+09       180.0
            2015           104341.0  2.694320e+09       180.0
Afghanistan 2019         38041754.0  2.173959e+10         NaN
            2018         37172386.0  2.112666e+10    652860.0
            2017         36296400.0  2.074494e+10    652860.0
            2016         35383128.0  2.020638e+10    652860.0
            2015         34413603.0  1.975974e+10    652860.0
Angola      2019         31825295.0  9.876968e+10         NaN
            2018         30809762.0  9.963591e+10   1246700.0
```

*emphasized text*

Hers is part of the code, I have taken out some functions to make it easier to read, I hope this doesn't stop people from understanding it.

```html
import pandas_datareader.wb as pdr  
import pandas as pd

get_wb_countries = pdr.get_countries()              
wb_countries = list(get_wb_countries['iso2c'])
#wbank_ind defined as series of codes from wb

df_wb = wb.download(indicator=wbank_ind,country=wb_countries,start=2015,end=2020)

# This is what I tried up to now to fetch most recent value :

sorted = df_wb.sort_values(by='year')
result = sorted.drop_duplicates('country', keep='last')

# I get an error message KeyError: Index(['country'], dtype='object')
```

Thanks for the help. Let me know if you need more information

Comment: A point of clarification ... would you want Aruba to return the 2017 line because that is the latest with all values present?

Comment: Yes that is the idea. I have in the meantime found a different library (world_bank_data) that uses the world bank API to actually search directly for the "most recent value" but it only works for one indicator at a time and I have about 50 indicators to export. I imagine I could create a loop to iterate the search and add the results column by column to a dataframe...I'm too much of a beginner though to figure out how exactly I would achieve this.

Comment: any chance you could supply a link to this data?

Comment: Hi, I have used a new library that allows me to get the most recent value directly from the world bank using their API. Now I can't quite figure out how to write all this data in one sinlge dataframe. The current script returns multiple dataframes for each worldbank_ind

Comment: import pandas as pd                 
import os
import world_bank_data as wb
import openpyxl                     
import xlsxwriter

path_folder = "C:/Users/Richard Mcnaughton/Desktop/Exercice Python/Project_Data_Annee_Strat/Data_sets"  
path_final_doc = os.path.join(path_folder,"final_project.xlsx")                                         

wbank_ind = ['NY.GDP.MKTP.KD','AG.LND.TOTL.K2','SP.URB.TOTL.IN.ZS', 'EN.POP.DNST','SP.POP.0014.TO'']                

for i in wbank_ind :
    print(wb.get_series(i,mrv=1))